# Word2Fo Java PlugIn

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xsl-fo

I'm using Word2Fo to generate XSL-FO code so that my Java application can generate a PDF instead of a Doc.  This is all well and good, and I've gotten the raw XSL-FO code now, but there's over a thousand lines of FO instructions, and it would be a pain to go over every single line to format it for Java output in w.write.

Is there any plugin for Word2Fo that can do this automatically on conversion?  Directing me to a Word2Fo Plugin library would be help in and of itself as well, since I can't seem to find one naturally existing anywhere.

Comment: Once you have xsl:fo, it should be easy to use Apache FOP to make a PDF from it.

Comment: The real issue is not generating the PDF so much, rather it's the hours it would take to convert each line by hand, to escape every double quote and add a w.write to the start of each line. 

Unless Apache FOP does that, and I'm just misunderstanding what the FOP is for/how it works.

Comment: Alas, this is exactly what FOP is for: generating some pretty output from xsl:fo. Your mileage may vary, as FOP does not implement all of XSL:FO, so it depends somewhat on the output from your plugin. Just give it a try, the proof is in the pudding :-)

Comment: After talking it over with a co-worker and my boss(!), I found that we can use our SQL database to make the XSL-FO code into a template, which our App can read in as needed.  This solves the problem for my needs. 

Thank you Gyro.  I appreciate your help and like your handle too. :)